# How to compile and install on an SD-Card installed different Linux

Tags: debian, arm, cross-compilation

I have an image of Raspbian on a SD-Card. Raspbian is configured to run on an arm. I have to do some installations inside this OS, but building on the Rasp costs a lot of time. So, is there a possibility to build from my development computer (x86_64) directly on the SD-card?

---

1st Edit

My developement system is Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 x86_64

Comment: First google search for `arm cross compiler` reveals this : http://www.acmesystems.it/arm9_toolchain

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can go about this:

- you can mount your SD card on your Ubuntu system and `chroot` into it, with a little setup (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/292449/86440 for details);
- you can cross-compile binaries on your Ubuntu system and copy them onto your SD card, using [`crossbuild-essential-armhf`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/build-essential).

Note that in the latter case, `armhf` don't have exactly the same definition on Ubuntu and Raspbian; if you have a newer Raspberry Pi the binaries should work, otherwise you'll need to either build your own cross-compiler toolchain, or use `crossbuild-essential-armel` (which will result in lower-performance binaries).